# Contexto User não retorna nome de usuário Asp Net Core 3.1 C#

Tags: c#, controller, injeção-de-dependência, asp-net-core, identity

Estou tentando obter o nome do usuário logado pelo contexto User dentro de um controller. Estou utilizando o Identity para gerenciar o login e JWT para autenticar as requisições na minha controller. Eu consigo obter os valores: `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` e  `User.Identity.AuthenticationType` normalmente, mas o `User.Identity.Name` sempre vem como `null`. O nome já está armazenado no banco normalmente.

Tentei pegar o Nome de outra forma, utilizando o `HttpContextAccessor`:

Dentro do método `ConfigureServices()` do arquivo Startup:

```
// Obs: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
// Declarando o HttpContextAccessor na Startup para ser utilizado em
// outras partes do programa
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Dentro do meu Controller:

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TesteController : ControllerBase
        {
            // Injetando o HttpContextAccessor no construtor:
            private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;
    
            public TesteController(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor)
            {
                _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                // Sempre retorna null, assim como o User.Identity.Name
                return Ok(_httpAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: olha isso aconteceu comigo num projeto aqui, basicamente opitei por pegar o email, que sempre tem (no meu caso)  :(

Comment: O que eu estou a fazer é junto com o JWT, adicionei mais informação (ClaimsIdentity). Depois podes utilizar essa informação como pretenderes. De realçar que esta informação é anexada ao token e é pública e estática Não podes guardar dados sensíveis ou dinâmicos.

Comment: O que você consegue obter na `User.Identity` e o que você tem persistido no banco? tentou a propriedade `DisplayName`?